# Not taking the input

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that only takes odd numbers, and if you input 0 it will output the addition and average, without taking any even number values to the average and the addition. I'm stuck with not letting it take the even values..
Heres my code so far:

```
    int num = 0;
    int addition = 0;
    int numberOfInputs = 0;

    cout << "Enter your numbers (only odd numbers), the program will continue asking for numbers until you input 0.." << endl;

    for (; ;) {

    cin >> num;
    numberOfInputs++;
    addition = addition + num;

    if (num % 2 != 0) {
     //my issue is with this part
        cout << "ignored" << endl;
    }

    if (num == 0) {
        cout << "Addition: " << addition << endl;
        cout << "Average: " << addition / numberOfInputs << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic here. Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` ....) then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` ....)

Comment: What? I don't know what that is I'm using Visual Studio i just run the code and it takes inputs and gives outputs shouldn't be too hard

Comment: Please let me know if my answer not solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution of your code:**

Your code doesn't working because of following reasons:

Issue 1: You adding inputs number without checking whether it's even or not

Issue 2: If would like skip even then your condition should be as follow inside of the loop:

```
if (num%2==0) {
cout << "ignored:" <<num << endl;
continue;
}
```

Solving your issues, I have update your program as following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num = 0;
int addition = 0;
int numberOfInputs = 0;

cout << "Enter your numbers (only odd numbers), the program will continue asking for numbers until you input 0.." << endl;

for (; ;) {

cin>> num;

 if (num%2==0) {
    cout << "ignored:" <<num << endl;
    continue;
}
numberOfInputs++;
addition = addition + num;



if (num == 0) {
    cout << "Addition: " << addition << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << addition / numberOfInputs << endl;
    break;
    }
 } 

}
```

Comment: Please let know if my code didn't solved your problem

Comment: You should explicitly say what you've changed.

Comment: I think you may need the break keyword? unless you want the code to go on indefinitely...

Comment: @KardoKamal No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    int sum=0;
    int average=0;
    int inputArray[20]; // will take only 20 inputs at a time
    int i,index = 0;
    int size;

    do{
    cout<<"Enter number\n";
    cin>>number;

    if(number==0){

        for(i=0;i<index;i++){
            sum = sum + inputArray[i];
        }

        cout << sum;
        average = sum / index;
        cout << average;

    } else if(number % 2 != 0){
               inputArray[index++] = number;
    } else 
    cout<<"skip";

    }
    while(number!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

You can run and check this code here https://www.codechef.com/ide
by providing custom input